# BDC types not coming up as crawled properties in SharePoint 2013 search

Tags: bcs, sharepoint-search, crawled-property

I am trying to setup search in my SharePoint 2013 site, using BCS, connecting to a .Net assembly which is exposing the types.

The first time I deployed the solution, the exposed types came up as `crawled properties`,  and I was able to map them to managed properties, and I could search successfully.

However, after I added a few more types to my .Net assembly, these are not coming up in the `crawled properties`. Any changes I make to my .Net assembly does not seem to bring up the properties.

How can I resolve this?

**edit**
I removed the Content source and the external content type, and then deployed my solution again; then I created the content source again and did a full crawl; still, I couldn't see the `crawled property`

Comment: did you perform the IIS reset after Updates?

Comment: Yes, I tried iisreset multiple times. Also, tried `Restart-Service spsearchhostcontroller` as I had read somewhere.

Comment: did you reimport the assembly?

Comment: Does your new exposed types have a value.? Crawled properties will be created only if has at least one value (can't be blank).

Reindex or full crawl is also required.

Comment: yes, they have value. Actually, two of them are mandatory date fields..

Comment: Does your crawl account have Execute permissions on the ECT and Read Permissions on the External Data?

Comment: Yes @MatthewMcDermott, the crawl account has full permissions on the ECT, and regarding external data, the .Net assembly is using the admin account on the db right now.

Comment: Have you tried to create an External List and then login as the crawl account to ensure that you are correct? What BCS results are you seeing in the crawl logs?